# Is there a "refresh now" option to sync the onedrive pbix file changes into workspace instead of waiting for 1 hour?

Tags: powerbi, onedrive

I have pbix file uploaded to onedrive.

In Power BI workspace I have selected the above file (from onedrive).

In dataset settings I can see that there is a onedrive refresh configured as hourly (time cannot be changed). This means that if any change is made to the onedrive file, then after about 1 hour the change is reflected in the power bi workspace.

Is there a "refresh now" option to sync the onedrive pbix file changes into workspace instead of waiting for 1 hour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Automate trigger on OneDrive file to refresh Power BI dataset, after file is updated.

Comment: That's to update the dataset data. I am asking about reflecting the pbix changes from onedrive

Comment: You can use Power Automate trigger and upload file as described here https://powerbi.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/upload-a-local-pbix-file-using-the-import-api/